# Elastix extension for Asterisk based SIP on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I've tried and looked everywhere for this kind of plugin where:

1. User calls our number: xxx-xxx-xxx
2. If any customer service agent is currently online in the platform a popup appears on the screen regarding the call.
3. The popup will have all the information regarding the customer (if they have their information already registered via the mobile / phone number they are currently calling from)
4. In most cases this is called a Dialer integration. However I'd like do do this with Magento 2 and Asterisk based SIP with either Elastix or any other software.